# get las record from group in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the next structure for db, i need to get only the most recent row by id, for example the most recen row for id 1, the most recen row for id 2, etc, for the moment i have this query:

```
SELECT  max(fecha), id_transaccion, id_movimiento
FROM transaccion_movimiento 
group by (id_transaccion, id_movimiento, fecha);
```

To later adapt to this:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  max(fecha), id_transaccion, id_movimiento FROM transaccion_movimiento  group by (id_transaccion, id_movimiento, fecha) ORDER BY ID_TRANSACCION asc LIMIT 1)nn ON T.id_transaccion = nn.id_transaccion LEFT JOIN ctl_tipo_movimiento IM ON IM.id_tipo_movimiento = nn.id_movimiento " +
```

Please i need help

[image: Imge with commands and results]

Comment: *please* in future, don't use images, especially images that are almost impossible to interpret. copy/paste of text is better. This may be useful: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you consider using `row_number() over()` instead. See [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
SELECT
      *
FROM x
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            fecha
          , id_transaccion
          , id_movimiento
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_transaccion, id_movimiento
                               ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS ultima_fecha_row
      FROM transaccion_movimiento
      ) nn ON T.id_transaccion = nn.id_transaccion asn nn.ultima_fecha_row=1
LEFT JOIN ctl_tipo_movimiento im ON im.id_tipo_movimiento = nn.id_movimiento
```

Now whilst I recognized *fecha* to mean date not much else made sense to me, so you may have to adjust this suggestion. For example I'm not sure if `id_movimiento` is needed in the "partition" or not.

```
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_transaccion
                               ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS ultima_fecha_row
```